# Finding the Max max number of a set of data

Tags: java

So I have a set of data for Max weather averages, and I have constructed a while loop:

I want it to ignore the first line, that is why I do: `scn.nextLine();`.

Take note that all of this is within the `main method`.

```
//MAX MAX
float maxMax = 0;

try {
  File file = new File("weather.txt");
  Scanner scn = new Scanner(file);
  scn.nextLine();

  String line;

  while (scn.hasNextLine()) {
    line = scn.nextLine();

    //MAX MAX
    String maxTempString = line.substring(102, 108);
    maxTempString.trim();
    float maxTemperature = Float.parseFloat(maxTempString);
    if (maxTemperature > maxTemperature) {
      maxMax = maxTemperature;
      System.out.println(maxTemperature);
    } 
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File: " + e + " not found");
  }
System.out.println(maxMax);
```

When I loop through this data, It outputs various data like:

`50.0
50.0
42.8
48.2
46.4
46.4
55.4
71.6
71.6
69.8
51.8
57.2`

Now I'm having a hard time with what I should do within the if statement, my current statement returns `0`

I just need some pointers, I am looking to find the Maximum number of the Max weather list. Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is minTemperature declared?

Comment: what is minTemperature. Shouldn't it be comparing against maxMax?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo @mayankTUM

Comment: Sorry that was a typo @FarhanRahman

Comment: `if (maxTemperature > maxTemperature)` ... you should rethink that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe

```
 if (maxTemperature > maxMax)
```

I don't know where minTemperature comes from.

Comment: wow, stupid logic on my part, i'll upvote you in 7 minutes, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Changing `if (maxTemperature > maxTemperature)` to `if (maxTemperature > maxMax)`
should do the trick.